# Extract HTML of an Elemeny

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get the internal HTML of an HTML Tag, how can i do this so far i have tried this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var x = parseInt("123");
    $("#getVal").html(x);
});

</script>
<?php
    $s = '<p id="getVal"></p>';
    echo strpos($s, ">");
    echo substr($s,15);

    $s = intval($s);
    echo gettype($s);
    echo intval($s)*2;
?>
```

after the last echo in php i just get 0 as result what i should i do to get the results.
Ok I want to do is sending some numeric data from JS to PHP and then after performing some numerical operations on it i want to return that user, on the same page. I dont want to use AJAX.

Comment: You want to extract or set??

Comment: i want to extract the data in between <p></p>

Comment: $("#getVal").html();

Comment: Is there any `p` is generated in html?

Comment: i think you want to get that data to be used in php which is in the same page of your page?

Comment: there is <p> in PHP snippet. You must see the code written in PHP as well

Comment: Check the output of the `php` code . It will  be - `14</p>integer0`

Comment: @roullie yes exactly i want to use that data in PHP

Comment: @Tahor You should take a look to JSON and PHP, or DOM in PHP

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **extract** the html, simply do

```
$("#getVal").html();
```

without passing any parameters to [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

If you want to **extract** the text, simply do

```
$("#getVal").text();
```

without passing any parameters to [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: No i want to extract the data with in <p></p>

Comment: @Tahir, how is the data. Is it text withing <p>?

Comment: i have a script top of the code which assigns value of "x" to HTML Tag <p></p> which is located in PHP snippet.

Comment: @AmmarCSE is is returning nothing !

Comment: @Tahir, can you reproduce it in a fiddle so I can better help?

Comment: @AmmarCSE can we write PHP in fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

To get the content of the element:

```
 $("#getVal").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, most of methods works as both getters and setters function. For example,

If you want to get something, like html content from an element, use the getter syntax

```
$("#getVal").html();
```

If you want to set something, like setting html content to an element, use the setter syntax.

```
$("#getVal").html("Hello dude!");
```